# How to log to a file when using Gunicorn

Tags: python, logging, flask, gunicorn

I am running a Flask app via gunicorn.

Prior to creating the Flask app I am setting logging using:

```
def setup_file_logging():
    logging.config.dictConfig(yaml.load(open('logging.conf')))
    logfile    = logging.getLogger('file')
    logfile.debug("<<setup_file_logging")
```

With logging.conf:

```
formatters:
  standard:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: standard
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: standard
    filename: errors.log
loggers:
  console:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
  file:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console,file]
```

If I run the application:

```
gunicorn manage:app
```

I only get the following in the log file:

2017-10-21 05:33:38,913 - file - DEBUG - <

ie no other logging events are written, even though the code base is peppered with logging calls where I get the logger using:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Running the code outside of gunicorn (python manage.py runserver) produces a rich log file so it seems that gunicorn is preventing logging information from being written to the log file (I want to use my own log file outside of gunicorn error log).

How can I allow set gunicorn to allow logging of all logging events in the application to a file>

Comment: this config works for me, what version are you using? ps, you need a `version: 1` entry in your config [as doc said](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details), and you'd better set `disable_existing_loggers=False`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since this was asked, however i had your same issue. If it helps anybody else, my solution was to modify the setup function, by modifying

```
logfile = logging.getLogger('file')
```

to

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

this allowed me to use logger in other modules by calling

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and get a structured logger name throughout the application.

some more explanation was found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apLoTRE1B8c&t=478s